# How to listen to the scrolling event of scrollviewer in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I have developed for windows 8/8.1. Its scrollviewer generates events while scrolling like - ViewChanging/ViewChanged.

I couldn't find any such event for scrollviewer in windows phone 8. How can i listen to when the scrollviewer is scrolling in WP8?

I am trying to look for method similar to -ScrollViewDidScroll() of iOS development.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are visual states for scrolling, maybe you could make use of those instead.

Comment: I am trying the adjust the bottom grid in relation to the scrollviewer on top of it. Right now I am able to do that through listening to "mousemove" event on scrollviewer. But, transition and effects are not very smooth. ui is jumping between states and sometimes mousemove event is also missed by hardware.

Comment: I tried searching for any event which is similar to -ScrollViewDidScroll() of iOS. But couldn't find any?

Comment: Hm, yeah I don't know.  Have you considered binding the bottom grid's position to the ScrollViewer's "VerticalOffset" property?

Comment: I am little new to WP8 dev. can you explain a little more about how can i go about binding grid's offset with scrollviewer. Or direct me to an example or blog. I will try to google for it in the meantime. Thank you.

Comment: I can try and recommend something, but it would help if you could post a concise version of your XAML setup.  What do you mean "Grid's offset", for example?  Grid doesn't normally have an offset, so are you referring to a custom control?

Answer (score 2):

Have tried to use this event? - [ScrollViewer.ViewChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged)

Comment: ViewChanged event is not available for the scrollviewer in windows phone 8 control.

Comment: +1 This is the only one that worked for me in WP 8.1 with a universal app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a ScrollViewer, or a ListBox you can listen to the LayoutUpdated event of the control and check the VerticalOffset. This is not ideal and is not updated as often as you would like, but will get you most of the way.

Here is an example using just a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer LayoutUpdated="OnScrollViewerUpdated">
    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
private void OnScrollViewerUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer) sender;

    // do something with scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
}
```

IF you are working with a LongListSelector from WP8, you can get updates immediately. You can hook into the ViewportControlof the LLS and get it's ViewPort location. Here is [a blog post detailing](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/01/16/Synching-the-scroll-position-of-two-LongListSelectors.aspx) how you could accomplish this.