# ListBox scrolling event in MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to hook to scroll event in WPF (Windows Phone7), in a MVVM manner? I'd like to detect when the list is scrolled to the bottom, and then do something. I tried something like this, but obviously it won't work:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxClick}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Scroll">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxScroll}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    (...)
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, I always look in the direction of *attached* behavior, because we need an independent solution that would work on the side UI and in the MVVM style. Attached behavior - is an attached property, which has an event handler to change this property and all the logic is implemented in this handler.

In this case you need to pass a Boolean value that indicates the beginning of behavior, and the command, what be executed when our condition is perform - scroll to the end of `ListBox`.

I created an example behavior where the key logic is here:

```
private static void scrollViewerScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;

    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        // Here we determine if the bottom reached
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
        {
            command = GetCommand(listBox);

            // Execute the command
            command.Execute(listBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of using:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:TestViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="TestArray" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <sys:String>Test1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test5</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test6</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test7</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test8</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test9</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Test10</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="TestListBox"
             AttachedBehaviors:ScrollingToBottomBehavior.IsEnabled="True"
             AttachedBehaviors:ScrollingToBottomBehavior.Command="{Binding TestButtonCommand}"
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource TestArray}"
             Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

**`TestViewModel`**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    private ICommand _testButtonCommand = null;

    public ICommand TestButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_testButtonCommand == null)
            {
                _testButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.TestButton(), null);
            }

            return _testButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    private void TestButton()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test command execute");
    }
}
```

**`ScrollingToBottomBehavior`**

```
public class ScrollingToBottomBehavior
{
    #region Private Section

    private static ListBox listBox = null;
    private static ICommand command = null;

    #endregion

    #region IsEnabledProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty;

    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject, string value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region CommandProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty;

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject DepObject, ICommand value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (ICommand)DepObject.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    static ScrollingToBottomBehavior()
    {
        IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled",
                                                            typeof(bool),
                                                            typeof(ScrollingToBottomBehavior),
                                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsFrontTurn));

        CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
                                                            typeof(ICommand),
                                                            typeof(ScrollingToBottomBehavior));
    }

    #endregion

    private static void IsFrontTurn(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            listBox.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(listBoxLoaded);
        }
        else 
        {
            listBox.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(listBoxLoaded);
        }
    }

    private static void listBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = GetFirstChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(listBox);

        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scrollViewerScrollChanged);
        }
    }

    #region GetFirstChildOfType

    private static T GetFirstChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dependencyObject == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetFirstChildOfType<T>(child);

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    #endregion

    private static void scrollViewerScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
            {
                command = GetCommand(listBox);
                command.Execute(listBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Complete sample project is available [`here`](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!126&authkey=!AAl7itAYzJm3uU0&ithint=file,.zip).

Comment: @Marek Małek: Unfortunately, I have not tested it under this platform, if will not work for you, let me know.

Comment: Sooo... Unfortunately it won't work under WP7.1 - `ScrollViewer` doesn't have the `ScrollChanged` event. Any advice?

Comment: @Marek Małek: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634708/how-to-listen-to-the-scrolling-event-of-scrollviewer-in-windows-phone-8) and [here](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/01/16/Synching-the-scroll-position-of-two-LongListSelectors.aspx) it shows the an alternative of `ScrollChanged` event, I hope you did find a solution himself, since I can not use the solution under `Windows Phone 7.1`.

Comment: Ok, I listen to the LayoutUpdated event. Thank you for the links!