# Detect user originated scroll in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, scroll

How can I detect a user originated scroll event in WPF? By user originated scroll I mean a scroll event caused by the **mouse** click on the **scroll bar** or by the user using the **context menu** of the scroll bar like in the screenshot.

[image]

The reason I want to know this is: I want to deactivate the autoscroll functionality that I have implemented when the user want to take manual control of the scroll position. The ListView that automatically scrolls down to the newly added elements by calling ScrollIntoView, should stop this behavior when the user does any manual scrolling.

Comment: `ListView` has `ScrollViewer` in its control template (which in turn has `ScrollBar`). You can get it (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21661821/1997232) question) and subscribe to its scroll events.

Comment: @Sinatr: the problem is ScrollChanged is triggered also by calling ScrollIntoView, so I cannot differentiate user input from programmatic scrolling using this event

Comment: Yes, you can. When you call `ScrollIntoView` set flag first, in the event check if flag is set to differentiate distinguish call from UI action.

Comment: @Sinatr: I tried your suggestion, but it does not work, WPF does not trigger the event while in the `ScrollIntoView` call, but later. And at that point a flag is useless since more then one events are sometimes generated for one `ScrollIntoView` call

Comment: @Sinatr: At this point I was sure the WPF pipeline with it's deferred rendering and event handling is kicking my ass, but when I checked the values of the `ScrollChangedEventArgs` I manage to figure an algorithm that detects the a user scroll. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Sinatr* suggested, I created a flag that remembers if a `ScrollIntoView` has been triggered. This solution seems to work just fine, but needed some handling of the `ScrollChangedEventArgs`

The relevant bits are in `scrollViewer_ScrollChanged`, but I provided a bit more code for context, The autoscroll is deactivated when the user tries to scroll up, and reactivated when he scrolls to the bottom.

```
private volatile bool isUserScroll = true;
public bool IsAutoScrollEnabled { get; set; }

// Items is the collection with the items displayed in the ListView

private void DoAutoscroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsAutoScrollEnabled)
        return;
    var lastItem = Items.LastOrDefault();
    if (lastItem != null)
    {
        isUserScroll = false;
        logView.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
    }
}

private void scrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VerticalChange == 0.0)
        return;

    if (isUserScroll)
    {
        if (e.VerticalChange > 0.0)
        {
            double scrollerOffset = e.VerticalOffset + e.ViewportHeight;
            if (Math.Abs(scrollerOffset - e.ExtentHeight) < 5.0)
            {
                // The user has tried to move the scroll to the bottom, activate autoscroll.
                IsAutoScrollEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The user has moved the scroll up, deactivate autoscroll.
            IsAutoScrollEnabled = false;
        }
    }
    isUserScroll = true;
}
```